# PyCharm не отображает файлы

Tags: pycharm

У меня есть папка `dist`, а PyCharm не знаю почему её не отображает. В консоли всё норм, даже если просто в папку зайти всё ок, но  он не отображает.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте в дереве навигации свернуть/развернуть папку проекта. Мне помогало

Comment: Да, знаю, тоже так делаю, но в этот раз не помогло

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Включите отображение исключенных файлов [image]

Comment: А где вы нашли эти настройки?

Comment: Куда вы нажали, чтобы появилось данное меню?

Comment: Поменял скриншот на более полный. Нажимать на шестеренку